# Play Framework Java signal from backend process

Tags: java, download, playframework, background-process

In my Play Framework 2 app, I am submitting a form based on which I start a process in the backend. This process does some work based on a file which was uploaded and creates a file which is to be downloaded. When the process finished and the function returns, I call ok(file) which allows the user to download the file.

The method to which I submit the form is like this:

```
public static AsyncResult runProcess() {

    //here I get the data from the form

    F.Promise<Boolean> callable = Akka.future(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {

            final ProcessRunner runProcess= new ProcessRunner ();
            return runProcess.invoke(parameters);
        }
    });
    return async(
          callable.map(
            new F.Function<Boolean,Result>() {

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Result apply(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
                    return ok(createZip(parameters)); //here I download the file
                }
            })
    );
}
```

I would like to put display a "processing" modal while the background process is running and then remove it once the file is ready to download. Before I submit the form, I open the modal, but I cannot remove the modal when the file download happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you show some code please? It's hard to see what you are doing without the code.

Comment: @hamena314 I put some code ^^ hope its helpful